# Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime direct call shortcut

Tags: direct-call

I was a apple user and had to switch to Android to take the benefit of dual SIM capabilities. I purchased a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime.

My question is how can I add speed dial or direct dial shortcut to my home screen, so that I can call my most frequent numbers using my preferred SIM with a single press?

I have seen people have this highly convenient feature in their phones. I can't figure out how to put this in my phone. I have both SIM (4G) cards inserted. The call needs to be generated from the SIM 2, if that information is required.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In google Play Store, search for a app called "Shortcut Dial." 
It's a 1x1 widget that will then prompt you to pick which contact 
(with whatever number you choose)
 to call with just one touch of the icon on one of your home screens.

Comment: Please add link to the app and important features that can help in this situation